# Scrollview disappers when clicking Checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-emulator, scrollview

My problem is that when I click my Checkboxthe `ScrollView` disappears. The checkbox uses a `OnCheckChangedListener`

This is a part of my layout file:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/drawingScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingTop="300dp" >

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/eraseButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rubber" />

        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/unschaerfeFilterCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Unschärfefilter AN/AUS"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/undoButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/undo" />

    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When I check and uncheck the checkbox the Layout should change:

```
unschaerfeFilterCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            // ab 6.2. Zeile
            CheckBox unschaerfeFilterCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.unschaerfeFilterCheckBox);
            TextView radiusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radiusTextView);
            TextView radiusTextMin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radiusMinTextView);
            SeekBar unschaerfeSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.unschaerfeSeekbar);
            RadioButton unschaerfeCheckBox1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.unschaerfeCheckBox1);
            RadioButton unschaerfeCheckBox2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.unschaerfeCheckBox2);
            RadioButton unschaerfeCheckBox3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.unschaerfeCheckBox3);
            RadioButton unschaerfeCheckBox4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.unschaerfeCheckBox4);

            ScrollView drawingScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.drawingScrollView);
            View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.vorschauView);

            if (isChecked) {

                drawingScrollView.invalidate();
                drawingScrollView.requestLayout();

                view.invalidate();
                view.requestLayout();

                radiusTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                radiusTextMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                unschaerfeSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                unschaerfeCheckBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                unschaerfeCheckBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                unschaerfeCheckBox3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                unschaerfeCheckBox4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                unschaerfeWertIsSet = true;
                unschaerfeLayoutIsSet = true;

                short abstandDurchsichtigkeitsTextOben = (short)(abstandStrichDickeTextOben + strichdickeTextHeight + konstanterAbstand);
                short height = (short)(drawingScrollView.getPaddingTop());

                short abstandUnschaerfeCheckBoxOben = (short)(abstandDurchsichtigkeitsTextOben + durchsichtigkeitsTextHeight + konstanterAbstand /*+ height*/);
                Log.d("abstandUnschaerfeCheckBoxOben", "abstandUnschaerfeCheckBoxOben " + abstandDurchsichtigkeitsTextOben + "|" + abstandUnschaerfeCheckBoxOben + "|" + height); // 64 bei Galaxy s2

                unschaerfeCheckBoxLayout.setMargins(0, abstandUnschaerfeCheckBoxOben, 0, 0);
                unschaerfeFilterCheckBox.setLayoutParams(unschaerfeCheckBoxLayout);

                short abstandRadiusTextLinks = (short)(unschaerfeCheckBoxWidth + konstanterAbstand);
                short abstandRadiusTextOben = (short)(abstandUnschaerfeCheckBoxOben + konstanterAbstand / 2);
                radiusTextViewLayout.setMargins(abstandRadiusTextLinks, abstandRadiusTextOben, 0, 0);
                radiusTextView.setLayoutParams(radiusTextViewLayout);

                short abstandRadiusMinTextLinks = (short)(abstandRadiusTextLinks + radiusTextViewWidth + konstanterAbstand);
                radiusMinTextViewLayout.setMargins(abstandRadiusMinTextLinks, abstandRadiusTextOben, 0, 0);
                radiusTextMin.setLayoutParams(radiusMinTextViewLayout);
```

...

The `ScrollView` is still disappered even when I uncheck the Checkbox. Everything works great in Emulator (API 16). The next thing is, that the position is incorrect on my mobile phone (API 19) but in Emulator the position is correct.

For illustration here are a few pictures:

(1): before pressing checkbox (mobile phone)
[image: before pressing checkbox (mobile phone)]

(2): after pressing checkbox (mobile phone) -> no `ScrollView` anymore, wrong position
[image: after pressing checkbox (mobile phone)]

(3): after pressing checkbox (emulator) -> everything all right
[image: after pressing checkbox (emulator)]

Let me know, when you need more java / xml

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView view = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
view.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
view.setFocusable(true);
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
        return false;
    }
});
```